# Accessing GPIO on OrangePI PC Plus ( H3 ) on Armbian 3.4.113 and newer

Tags: gpio, orange-pi

how to access GPIO on Armbian 3.4.113 on OrangePi PC plus ( SoC H3 ) now that the old method using `gpio-sunxi` and editing the `.fex`-file is obsolete ( want to share this  ... )

Answer (score 13):

The general proceeding is described in  https://linux-sunxi.org/GPIO

The GPIO pins are accessed via the `sysfs` file system. For enabling a specific pin it has to be exported into `/sys/class/gpio/export`

for pin *PA1* the command would be  `echo 1 > sys/class/gpio/export`.  The pin number is calculated by the following formula :

```
  (position of letter in alphabet - 1) * 32 + pin number
```

*PA1* has pin number ('*A*' is the 1st letter ) `1`,  *PB2* has pin number `34` ('*B*' is 2nd letter ), *PG7* has pin number `199`( '*G*' is 7th letter (7-1)*32+7=199 )

the positions on the **physical** header are different again, cf. the graphic below

so for enabling PG7 that is pin 40 on the physical header can be used

```
   echo 199 > sys/class/gpio/export
```

[image: OrangePi PC plus GPIO header]

*source of image : https://orange314.com/Hardware*

normally the echo command like   `echo "199"  sys/class/gpio/export`  gives a `Permission denied` error

an easy solution are the following:

To do a one-off manipulation of a GPIO pin, you have to start a
separate shell as a superuser first, then use echo. For instance to
turn pin A10 on:

```
$ sudo sh
# echo 10 > /sys/class/gpio/export
# echo out > /sys/class/gpio/gpio10/direction
# echo 1 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio10/value
```

Or you can use tee to avoid creating a subshell:

```
$ echo 10 | sudo tee /sys/class/gpio/export
$ echo out | sudo tee /sys/class/gpio/gpio10/direction
$ echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/class/gpio/gpio10/value
```

*source: https://forum.armbian.com/index.php?/topic/4052-problem-using-gpio-pins-on-legacy-kernel/*

An alternative would be to create a new group  and change the group of the /sys/class/gpio directory to this new group :

you can create a group called gpio, add the user to it, export the gpio
etc as follows:

```
sudo groupadd gpio
sudo usermod -aG gpio <myusername>
su <myusername>
sudo chgrp gpio /sys/class/gpio/export
sudo chgrp gpio /sys/class/gpio/unexport
sudo chmod 775 /sys/class/gpio/export
sudo chmod 775 /sys/class/gpio/unexport
```

This gives your user the ability to export and un-export.

Once you export the pins you can chgrp and chmod them as well (don't
forget their contents) and use them as usual.

```
echo "18" > /sys/class/gpio/export
chgrp -HR /sys/class/gpio/gpio18
chmod -R 775 /sys/class/gpio/gpio18
```

Now your user has access to the first GPIO pin 18.

*source : https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=5185*

when executing the `echo` with permissions a new directory appears in `/sys/class/gpio` i.e. for PA2 ( which is pin number 2 and number 22 on the physical header ) it is `/sys/class/gpio/gpio2`

to configure pin number 2 you have to write specific values to the files in  `/sys/class/gpio/gpio2`

for i.e. setting pin 2 to output and 'high' write

`echo "out" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio2/direction`

`echo "1" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio2/value`

when shutting down GPIO the pins should be unexported with i.e.

`echo 2 > /sys/class/gpio/unexport` for pin 2 ( *PA2*, number *22* on the physical header )

An alternative for accessing GPIO is using python, however for the H3 based boards the WiringOP is not available yet