# The group of gpio is reset after reboot the Orangepi 5 plus

Tags: ubuntu, ros, sys, udev, orange-pi

I am using OrangePi 5 plus and followed the answer in this link [text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46463724/accessing-gpio-on-orangepi-pc-plus-h3-on-armbian-3-4-113-and-newer), the group is changed to gpio, which contains my local user, but after reboot the group is reset to root. how can I permanently change the group? Or will there be some conflicts of `udev` rules, which is in this link [text](https://opi-gpio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#non-root-access)

And another general question, when I develop on this kind of platform, should I use root at the first time?

Information:

- hard ware:

  - name:           OrangePi 5 plus
  - chips:          rockchip-rk3588
  - structure:      Arm64
- OS:

  - version:        Ubuntu 22.04
  - kernel version: 5.10
  - python version: 3.10

Thank you for your help!

have tried: mentioned above
expecting:  permanently change the group of `/sys/class/gpio` to `gpio` after reboot.